# What strategy can I use to choose points for approximating an expensive-to-compute function?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation-theory

Suppose:

- I have some function $f(x)$ which is very expensive to compute
- I do not have a way to calculate its derivative (except as a numerical approximation given nearby points $f(x)$)
- I have enough computation resources to compute it at $N$ points within some interval $x\in[x_1,x_2]$.

Are there any algorithms to help choose those N points such that I can minimize the error from some kind of approximation, e.g. a spline or piecewise Chebyshev approximation?

Just as an example, consider the following function in the interval $[0,2]$:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{e^{40(x-1)}+1} + \frac{x^2}{4e^{40(1-x)}+4}$$

It is very polynomial in subintervals $[0,3/4]$ and $[5/4,2]$, but has sharp curvature near $x=1$; in this case I'd want to put most of the $N$ points concentrated near $x=1$. But that would require me to know something about the function ahead of time. Is there a strategy that selects points as you go? For example, start evaluating at $x={0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},2}$, and then look numerically to select intervals that need more points than others.

[image]

Comment: There's [Remez's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Remez's_algorithm) for example. Depending on your needs, you could try to modify it for other tyoes of estimations. If you can't compute derivatives, you can use estimates instead.

Comment: I'm familiar with Remez (somewhat) and Chebyshev approximation; I usually just use Chebyshev approximation since it's good enough. But the problem is not how to approximate a function given points -- the problem is how to choose the points. And I know about [Chebyshev nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes), but that assumes the range of interest is well-matched to Chebyshev approximation. In my case I do not know ahead of time where the "ugliness" is. If I throw Chebyshev approximation at it, it requires an extremely high degree -- what I really want to do is range reduction....

Comment: ...but in order to choose subintervals I need a strategy to decide where to split the range based on some limited number of samples available.

Comment: Remez's algorithm *is* about how to choose your points. Given some sequence of points used, it iteratively finds a better one.

Comment: Does it incorporate the "cost" of new information? (e.g. using old data is "free" in my case, whereas evaluating new points is computationally expensive)

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Remez's_algorithm): "One must also be able to calculate the first and second derivatives of f(x). Remez's algorithm requires an ability to calculate $f(x),\,f'(x),\,$ and $f''(x)$ to extremely high precision. " -- oh, that's a non-starter :/ No derivatives allowed in my case; i'll make that clear.

Comment: Also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm), with a reference: "the current node $x_i$ is replaced with... $\bar x_i$... No high precision is required here, the standard *line search* with a couple of *quadratic fits* should suffice.$^{[9]}$" In particular, you may incorporate previous calculations into the line search to avoid recomputation, and by quadratic fits they are likely referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_parabolic_interpolation) (a.k.a. Jarratt's method).